# How to set correct ACL to website users?

Tags: acl, setfacl

I'm trying to set correct ACL to all folders used on my shared server. That way other users will be unable to read each other files. What I did so far is next:

Owner of each website folder is owned by separate user and group:

```
ls -l crm

drwxr-x--- 3 crm         crm         4096 Jan  6 04:54 crm
drwxr-x---  3 mdf        mdf         4096 Jan  8 00:26 mdf
drwxr-x--- 3 dba         dba         4096 Jan  6 04:54 dba
```

Permissions are set to `-rwxr-x---`, so others have 0 permission.

But because apache (`www-data`) need execute permission, by default that will not work (`error: AH00035`).

That way I've decided to use setfacl and to give www-data execute and read permission:

```
setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rx /var/www/crm/
```

getfacl will give:

```
# file: crm
# owner: crm
# group: crm
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
```

Now website works fine, but I'm not sure if what I did is correctly done? Will this kind of configuration be enough to isolate users from reading each other files?

Comment: Note that if you allow scripting (PHP, CGI, etc.), you need to check under what user those scripts will run, as well. (Unless you use `suexec`, it's probably the same for all your users.)

Comment: I'm running php-fpm - all of them (users) are separated same way as above.